# DataGridView Multiple Selected Columns get both row data

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach

Thanks StackOverflow !

The Below code is intended to selected and run through each row.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in RGV.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (RGV.SelectedColumns.Contains(cell.OwningColumn))
                { row.Cells["Status"].Value = "OK"; }

                else
                { row.Cells["Status"].Value = "Check"; }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is couple of errors in your code. First, you are trying to assign a DatagridViewColumn to a DatagridViewRow, which is build-able but i really dont know how it will react.

As answer to your question i would suggest something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in RGV.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            row.Cells["Status"].Value = "Check";
            if (RGV.SelectedColumns.Contains(cell.OwningColumn))
            { 
                row.Cells["Status"].Value = "OK";
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope i helped you somehow.

Comment: Cannot get "ok" to show in Status Column of each row when the selection of the cells in the row are the same.                                    Edited Post with new code.

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand your next problem. Also I would suggest to try something more similar to code above. I edited it. Your code only fills cell with ok if you selected last column.

Comment: Correct. the problem I had with the code given evven though it worked temporarly was that it would, or seem like it would... deselect the columns and it was not testing them correctly... I did find a work around though which I will post as well. Definatly give you credit though because without you I wouldnt of been able to fix my issue!   THANKS BORIS !....Though this could be also that I have never used .owningcolumn  before. seems interesting for me to research.